# How to only refresh the div that the user has clicked from

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to refresh the div that the user clicked on whereby the divs' id are based on the the id of data fetched from the database.

**Lets say**
if user clicked div with id **#topic-4** it should only refresh that div after successfully doing the ajax operation. but my problem is i dont know how to handle the dynamically generated ids for the divs

I believe the problem is in my ajax code

```
$('#topic-4').load(location.href + ' #topic-4');
```

One thing to keep in mind is that the ids **topic-4...** are fetched dynamically from the database. I also wish to keep the ajax code outside the repeating region

**My ajax code**

```
$(function() {

$(document).on("click", ".first", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var uid = $(this).data('id');

    $.get('vote.php?id=' + uid, function(html){

        $('#topic-4').load(location.href + ' #topic-4');

         });

});

});
```

The topics are fetched from the database and repeated inside a do while php as illustrated:

```
<?php do { ?>

<div class="first" id="topic-<?php  $row_topics['id']; ?>">

 <a href="#" data-id="<?php echo $row_topics['id']; ?>" class="btn"> click </a>

</div>

<?php } while ($row_topics = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_topics));   ?>
```

**Result**

```
<div class="first" id="topic-1">
 <a href="#" data-id="1" class="btn"> click </a>  
</div>

<div class="first" id="topic-2">
 <a href="#" data-id="2" class="btn"> click </a>  
</div>

<div class="first" id="topic-3">
 <a href="#" data-id="3" class="btn"> click </a>  
</div>

...and soon
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you re-explain what the actual problem is?

Comment: His problem is that he clicks in the div id 4 and he gets all divs inside that div, not only div 4 information, so he is not refreshing div id 4, he is re getting all divs inside div id 4

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez I even dont know why. Do you have a better idea

Comment: @Jeff i have added something from **....lets say**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$.get('vote.php?id=' + uid, function(html) {
    $.get(location.href + '?' + (new Date()).getTime(), function(response) {
        var newTopic = $(response).find('#topic-' + uid);
        $('#topic-' + uid).html(newTopic.html());
    });
});
```

`location.href + '?' + (new Date()).getTime()` makes it reload page for sure, without any cache.

Than, you constructing a new jQuery object via `$(response)` and search in it desired topic.

After that, you assigning new value to your current topic.

It should work without any changes in your `php` code.

---

to make it simpler, you must change your `vote.php` so it'll return only a new upvoted topic html, than you can do:

```
$.get('vote.php?id=' + uid, function(response) {
    $('#topic-' + uid).html(response);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort What is `newTopic.html()` ?

Comment: @krushiovida, `newTopic.html()` returns an `innerHTML` of the `<div id="topic-<num>">` in the response. My new update is way more correct solution of this situation.

Comment: Now i get it. i will give it a try.

Comment: @krushiovida, remember, your `vote.php` must return only `innerHTML` of the upvoted topic, that is without main `<div class="first" id="topic-<?php  $row_topics['id']; ?>">` and it's closing pair.

Comment: am still trying to manipulate your idea. it works when i use it like this  `$('#topic-' + uid).load('#topic-' + uid);` but another problem arises. The div first duplicates then refreshes the div then it becomes normal. The new problem is the duplication of a div

Comment: Finaly figured out your approach. I had to put the whole voting div in a separate page for it to work out  `$('#topic-' + uid).load('topic.php?topicID=' + uid);`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are getting all the `DIVS` again, as you showed us in your PHP (not complete) code.

Write all your PHP code that handle that `GET` so we can give you more help. The main problem is in your SQL syntax, because you can filter there.

Comment: My problem is not the php code completely. the problem is the refreshing. even if the codes return negative or positive results still the div should refresh